# $y=f(x) \in C^1$ is defined implicitly by $ax + by = f(x^2+y^2), f'(x) = ?$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

#### Problem

$y=f(x) \in C^1$ is defined implicitly by $ax + by = f(x^2+y^2)$. $a$ and $b$ are constants . $f'(x) = ?$

#### Analysis

The answer for this exercise given by my teacher is $$f'(x) = \frac{2xf'(x^2+y^2)-a}{b-2yf'(x^2+y^2)}$$ I can't agree with that. Because if you express a derivative function with itself, in fact you don't find it.

Is it possible to write the expression of $f'(x)$ with only $x, y, a $ and $b$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are $f$'s involved in $y = f(x)$ and $ax+by = f(x^2+y^2)$ the same function? In such case, we obtain the following non-linear functional equation $$ax + bf(x) = f(x^2+f(x)^2)$$ and differentiating both sides gives $$ a + bf'(x) = f'(x^2+f(x)^2)(2x+2f(x)f'(x)). $$ Rearranging this gives the same answer as your teacher provided. But the problem of determining an expression which is not 'self-referential' is more or less the same as solving the functional equation, which I see no obvious way.

Comment: @SangchulLee: that's exactly what the teacher did, and it's not what is asked here.

Comment: @TA123: I edited the typo in the question, not sure if it's yours or your teacher's.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, I understand. In the original commend (which is now modified), I wanted to make things clear as the setting seemed unusual. Anyway, I am not sure as to whether we can find a closed-form solution of this equation, which is more or less the same as finding $f'(x)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thx. I made that typo carelessly.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}
y=f(x) \\
ax + by = f(x^2+y^2)
\end{cases}$$
In fact this is a functional equation :
$$ax + bf(x) = f(x^2+f(x)^2)$$

The unknown is the function $f$. But it is not asked to solve the functional equation, which seems very difficult.

The question appears ambiguous. From the given answer it seems that it is asked for the relationship between the derivatives $f'(x)$ and $f'(x^2+y^2)$. If this is the meaning of the question, a way to obtain the wanted relationship is shown below, using the differentials of the above functions.

$dy=df(x)=f'(x)dx$

$df(x^2+y^2)=f'(x^2+y^2)d(x^2+y^2)=f'(x^2+y^2)\big(2xdx+2ydy \big)$

$df(x^2+y^2)=f'(x^2+y^2)\big(2xdx+2yf'(x)dx \big)$

$df(x^2+y^2)=2f'(x^2+y^2)\big(x+yf'(x) \big)dx$

$$ax+by=f(x^2+y^2) \quad\implies\quad a_,dx+b\,dy=df(x^2+y^2)$$
$$a\,dx+b\,f'(x)dx=2f'(x^2+y^2)\big(x+yf'(x) \big)dx$$
$$a+bf'(x)=2f'(x^2+y^2)\big(x+yf'(x) \big)$$
$$f'(x)\big(b-2yf'(x^2+y^2) \big)=2f'(x^2+y^2)-a$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{2xf'(x^2+y^2)-a}{b-2yf'(x^2+y^2)}$$

Of course, this doesn't give the explicit derivatives $f'(x)$, but gives the relationship between the couples of derivatives at different values $(x)$ and $(x^2+y^2)$. This is probably what is expected because solving for explicit $f(x)$ or explicit $f'(x)$ is far to be an exercise of normal level for students.

Comment: Thank your answer. Yes, explicit $f'(x)$ is far for normal level students. But that's why I ask this question here.

Comment: OK. I don't think that it is possible to write the expression of $f'(x)$ with only $x, y, a $ and $b$. This would require to solve the functional equation (or it's derivative), which is beyond the reach.